# Rebar eunit runs non native (non Hipe) code

Tags: erlang, rebar, erl, eunit, hipe

I have compiled my Erlang module using

```
rebar compile
```

using the following option in rebar.config

```
{erl_opts, [native, {hipe, [verbose]}, warnings_as_errors, debug_info]}.
{eunit_compile_opts, [native, {hipe, [verbose]}, warnings_as_errors, debug_info]}.
```

I see that the code is indeed compiled to native since I see Hipe messages during compilation and the .beam file size are also larger than non-native compilation.

However when I run

```
rebar eunit
```

which tests my module I always get false for

```
 code:is_module_native(?MODULE)
```

within my module under test.

Why does rebar not run my eunit test as native code?

I have additionally added this line to the reltool.config file,

```
 {app, hipe, [{incl_cond, include}]},
```

rebar 2.1.0-pre 17 20140421_192321 git 2.1.0-pre-166-ged88055

Answer (score 1):

Your code is recompiled when you run "rebar eunit" using the compile options defined by

- `{erl_opts, [native, {hipe, [verbose]}, warnings_as_errors, debug_info]}.`

and modified by the compile options defined by

- `{eunit_compile_opts, [???]}.`

Did you check these options?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added eunit_compile_opts (see edited question). Still it runs non-native.